# Store users information in a single file on the root of the web server JavaScript/HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, database, forms-authentication, credentials, intranet

I'm trying to do an authentication system for a website that is supposed to be stored on an intranet. The guy told me he wanted the credentials of the users (max 10 users) to be stored on a single file with some kind of protection. Do you have suggestions.? I really tried to find information, maybe I am not searching for the right thing but everybody uses mondoDB in this kind of situation. Which is not stored locally.
be gentle please... I trying to do it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mentioned a single file on the server, I thought of SQLite. As per the [projects description](https://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html):

> The complete state of an SQLite database is usually contained in a single file on disk called the "main database file".

But passwords - even on an intranet server - should never be stored in plain text. And one-way hashing where the source code is also present does not sound like a good idea.

However, [sqlcipher](https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher) seems to solve both those issues. As a starter, you might want to setup a brief tester with plain SQLite.([Here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/) is one simple tutorial).

From there you can look at a sample like this [one](https://coolaj86.com/articles/building-sqlcipher-for-node-js-on-raspberry-pi-2/) which shows how **sqlcipher** could be used with a JavaScript engine like Node.js.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and what if I just put a password on the file?

Comment: Two points come to mind: (1) plain text passwords in text file keep me up at night. :) And (2) if you use a fast local DB like SQLite, you can actually create an interface to manage passwords and users, as opposed to going on to the server and editing the file.

Comment: thank you :3 do you have a suggestion for wich easy password database creation library I must use?

Comment: because right now I am totallylost and must do it fast

Comment: and without using an extern server for the database, I really want to store it localy

Comment: - [This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_installation.htm) will show you how to install SQLite on Mac, Windows and Linux.  -[This](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/) will show you how to use the NPM package for Node.js.   I hope that helps.

Comment: thank you I am trying to use it. Do you know a trustfull video explanation?

Comment: That one I am afraid I do not know. I have found it most practical to take a tutorial (like the links I gave) and from the outset customise it for the project I have in mind. That way, when I have completed the tutorial, my program is also well under way.

Comment: @TheHiddenGeek: Did SQLite solve the issue for you?

Comment: it could but I am still trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

I've tried like that to make it easy

[The Javascript Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WIg8.png)

Answer (score 0):

SOOOOO, i ended up using nedb... VOILA